# Regex expression wont work with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this data:

```
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|CABELAS|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|FX4|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|FX4|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|HARLEY-DAVIDSON EDITION|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|KING RANCH|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|LARIAT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|LARIAT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|LARIAT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XL|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XL|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XL|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XLT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XLT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XLT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|CABELAS|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|FX4|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|FX4|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|HARLEY-DAVIDSON EDITION|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|KING RANCH|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|LARIAT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|LARIAT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|LARIAT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XL|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XL|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XL|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2008|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XLT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2009|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XLT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
49780|Truck|2010|FORD|F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP|XLT|6.4L DIESEL V8|||Crew Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed|Extended Cab w/81.8 in./6 ft. 9.8 in. Bed
```

I wrote this regular expression using RegExr. It capture the 5th column (delimited by |) if the row is a match:

```
.*\|.*\|2010\|ford\|(.*)\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*
```

When I run a preg_match_all on it, I get this error:

```
preg_match_all() [<a href='function.preg-match-all'>function.preg-match-all</a>]: Unknown modifier '*'
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/oxFBk --- your regex works without errors

Comment: I'm really curious as to why the fourth row from the bottom in your data has different syntax highlighting than the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), and it looks like you want a [case insensitive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) match as well:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/.*\|.*\|2010\|ford\|(.*)\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*/i', $subject, $matches);
```

Comment: This works great - I accepted the answer. This is probably my lack of understanding - but it only returns one match (F-350 SUPER DUTY PICKUP) when it should return two (F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP as well)